# How to tell if a JFrame window has already been opened?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, singleton

I have a `JFrame` with a `Button` that opens a different `JFrame`.  But I want the button to only open the second frame **once**.  Problem is, every time I click it I get a new instance of the frame.  This **must** be a very common problem, since I'm following a book on how to create this GUI.  I find it odd that the author didn't mention this "feature".

So how do I keep my button from opening multiple copies of the new frame?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

You should keep a reference to the sub frame you open for first time. At second time you first check if you have a reference or not and then decide to create a new frame or to put the focus onto the existing open frame.

**Example as answer to comment of OP** (similar to other answer of @AlexanderTorstling, but not immediately creating the sub frame):

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame {
  private JFrame subFrame = null;

  MainFrame() {
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (subFrame == null) {
           subFrame = new JFrame();
           ...
         }
         subFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });    
  }
}
```

This example has also the advantage to give you the possibility to close the subframe via a registered `WindowAdapter` if the main frame is closed.

Comment: This is how I would have tried to do it, but how?

How do you "check if you have a reference or not"?  

Code example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of letting the button create a new JFrame every time, make the second JFrame a member of the first JFrame, and only let the button call `jframe2.setVisible(true);`:

```
class JFrame1 {
   JFrame2 jframe2=...;
   JButton button=...;

   JFrame1() {
     ...
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         jframe2.setVisible(true);
       }
     });
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED!

try this:

```
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame(); // instance variable

...

//when button is clicked
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!frame2.isVisible())
            frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

make sure you are handling the closing of all of the JFrames manually like this:

```
frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // handle closing the window
        frame2.setVisible(false);
        frame2.dispose();
    }
});
```

instead of using the `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but, wouldn't this solution still create an instance of the frame, even though it would be invisible?

Comment: thanks. i updated my answer and now it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code snippet:

```
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame(); // instance variable
boolean secondWindowIsOpne = false;

//when button is clicked
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(secondWindowIsOpne == false){
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        secondWindowIsOpne  = true;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("This Window is already running");
   
  }
   });
```

Make sure you are handling the closing of all of the JFrames manually like this:

```
frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // handle closing the window
      secondWindowIsOpne = false;
    frame2.setVisible(false);
    frame2.dispose();
}

 });
```